# How to back out commits in GIT repository on DevOps

Tags: git

How do I back out commits made in GIT repository on DevOps. Other than manually changing back the code and re-pushing/committing for deployment I am unable to successfully carry this out within the GIT repository on DevOps. 
I have tried the various features within the repository but cannot quite get it right.

For example - I am on Build 370 but would like to roll back to Build 365, deleting the changes made since.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

- Clone the repository (or use a local clone that you have)
- Run `git reset --hard Build365` (or whatever the SHA hash is)
- Run `git push -f *repository* HEAD:*master*` (or whatever the branch is)

The force push will require that you have force push permissions on the server.